# PyQGIS: problem with parametrs

Tags: python, pyqgis

I would like to select records 0-10 in INPUT. Algorithm works in QGIS Python console, but in cmd I'm getting error:

```
"Could not load source layer for INPUT: 
  C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/budynki/budynkishp.shp|subset=\"fid\" >=0 and \"fid\" <= 10 not found."
```

What is the problem?

```
processing.run("native:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':r'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/budynki/budynkishp.shp|subset=\"fid\" >=0 and \"fid\" <= 10',
                                                   'JOIN':r'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/adresy/adresyzukladem.shp',
                                                   'PREDICATE':[1,5],
                                                   'JOIN_FIELDS':['PNA','SIMC_id','SIMC_nazwa','ULIC_nazwa','Numer'],
                                                   'METHOD':0,
                                                   'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':True,
                                                   'PREFIX':'',
                                                   'OUTPUT':r'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/caloscpython.shp'})
```

Comment: What if you define your subset before inputting it into the processing algorithm? Like `layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/budynki/budynkishp.shp|subset=\"fid\" >=0 and \"fid\" <= 10'" , "testlayer_shp", "ogr")` and the try `print(layer)` or `layer.isValid()`, and if everything is fine run the `processing.run("native:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':layer, ... })`.

Comment: I have got empty layer so it didn't work.

Comment: So, maybe check this layer `"C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/budynki/budynkishp.shp|subset=\"fid\" >=0 and \"fid\"`

Comment: I tried and got (JOINED_COUNT': 0, 'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/caloscpython.shp'}). I should got JOINED_COUNT': 2. I think "subset=\"fid\" >=0 and \"fid\" <= 10" didn't work.